# Why does R prop.test result is different than online calculators?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value

Let's say I ran an a/b test for 1000 impressions in each group. Treatment had 130 conversions while control had only 100. See data below:

| group | visitors | conversions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| control | 1000 | 100 |
| treatment | 1000 | 130 |

I've ran this data in prop test and had a p-value of ~4%

```
prop.test(c(100,130), c(1000,1000))
```

```
    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(100, 130) out of c(1000, 1000)
X-squared = 4.1317, df = 1, p-value = 0.04209
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.058932066 -0.001067934
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.10   0.13
```

Then I ran the same data in an [online calculator](https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/ab-testing-significance-calculator/) and received 1% p-value. I tried it in several calculators with similar results.

Can someone explain to me the reason for difference?

Comment: Playing with the online calculator, changing between two-sided and one-sided hypothesis does not change the $p$-value (though it does change the claimed power) when I think it should

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the online calculator result by running:

```r
prop.test(c(100,130), c(1000,1000), correct = FALSE, alternative = 'less')
```

Thus, it seems that the difference is due to two separate reasons:

1. R applies [Yates' continuity correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates%27s_correction_for_continuity) by default
2. For some reason, the p-value reported in the online calculator is the one-sided p-value. R doubles the p-value in the case of a two-sided test.